# Weighted average optical spectra in VASP

Tags: vasp, optical-properties, 2d-lattice, gw-bse

I am working on a 2D system where geometric and magnetic isomers are energetically very close to each other (orders of meV). I am interested in optical absorbance spectra using GW+BSE approach but I am curious whether its possible to create average absorption spectra since in a real life situation the material would most likely be composed of several domains with different magnetic motifs and not just the one with the lowest energy.

I know that there's a way with Boltzmann probability $p_i$
$$
p_i = \mathrm{exp}\left(-\frac{E_i}{k_{\mathrm{B}}T}\right)/\left[\sum_j\mathrm{exp}\left(-\frac{E_j}{k_{\mathrm{B}}T}\right)\right],
$$
but is there a way to do it such that it includes zero point energies, or a entirely different way altoghether.

Comment: I gave my +1 long ago, but since it has been more than 6 months, is there any update you can provide us? Are you still urgently or actively in need of an answer to this question? Please let us know!

Comment: Sorry for the late response. Unfortunately, I haven't been able to find an answer to this question and I had to proceed without a satisfying conclusion.